# SSH Reverse Tunnel keeps disconnecting with activity

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I set up an SSH Reverse tunnel using `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -R 2222:localhost:22 username@remoteserver.com`. The tunnel connect to the remote server and opens port 2222. I connect into the tunnel with `ssh -p 2222 user@tunnelclient` and it works fine. 
I jump into the tunnel and land on the other machine. A few minutes go by an then the remote host closes the connection.

I start a ping to keep the activity going, and still, the remote host (the client that starts the tunnel to the remote server) drops the connection.

Q: How can I stop this from happening?

```
... snip ...
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=70 ttl=64 time=0.080 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=71 ttl=64 time=0.079 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=72 ttl=64 time=0.076 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=73 ttl=64 time=0.080 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=74 ttl=64 time=0.080 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=75 ttl=64 time=0.080 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=76 ttl=64 time=0.080 ms
Connection to localhost closed by remote host.
Connection to localhost closed.
user@remoteserver:~$
```

Comment: This is often caused by an unstable network connection. You could try monitoring with `netstat -i` at each end. If possible, you could run the ssh server and/or client with the `-d` option and it should tell you why it is closing the connection.

Comment: it was the `Type=` field in the systemd service.

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem. I solved it by changing the systemd service `Type=` from `forking` to `simple` see below.

```
[Unit]
Description="SSH Reverse Tunnel Service"
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=dev
Restart=always
ExecStart=/bin/ssh -vvv -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -R 2222:127.0.0.1:22 remoteuser@remoteserver

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now it works well and seems to be stable.